# Android studio TextInputEditText Style with Oval edges is working but when it expands it becomes ugly,how to fix the edges

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

So, I created a TextInputEditText with oval edges using this code:

XML Oval Shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="50dp"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#44433A"/>
<solid android:color="#FFF"/>
```

here is the TextInputEditText:(I know the style should be inside the style.xml file)

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/Ti1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/oval"
                android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                android:hint="@string/hint_Note"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="8"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="50dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                 />
```

here you see that when a person goes to the 2nd line it expands to a maximum set as 8 lines,but my problem here is when it expands it starts forming a full oval but i want it to become this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="5dp"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#44433A"/>
<solid android:color="#FFF"/>
```

my first assumption was that I should change the background when the lines expand further than 1 line, but I don't know if this is a good solution or not,is there a better solution, I am trying to mimic the new Whatsapp bottom EditText behavior when it comes to expanding the EditText.

[I am able to reach this shape on the edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O6Ni.jpg)

[as the line expands the edge creates a small vertical line between the round edges of the edittext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naZgf.png)

[as you might see that upon reaching 3 lines the line is still increasing in length on both left and right sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQtAD.png)

[another example upon reaching 4 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utoEL.png)

but when I try to write something in my TextInputEditText  it expands but it does not create a straight vertical line on the left and right edges, it starts to form an oval.

Comment: Can you add the expected behavior ? Maybe a GiF.

Comment: @ADM Added pictures since i could not find a GIF and i don't have time to create a GIF right now.

Comment: @ADM isn't `<corners android:radius="50dp"/>` supposed to to change the radius of all corners

Comment: I think this is the behavior . I just checked what's app and showing the same . except its min height is of 2 lines .

Comment: It&#39;s the default behavior. I just checked what&#39;s app and it&#39;s showing the same . Except it&#39;s min height is of 2 lines. So after 2 lines the background radius will be tored ..